# Loading each .py file in a path - imp.load_module complains about relative import

Tags: python, import

I am trying to parse a given path for python source files, import each file and DoStuff™ to each imported module.

```
def ParsePath(path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for source in (s for s in files if s.endswith(".py")):
            name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(source))[0]
            m = imp.load_module(name, *imp.find_module(name, [root]))
            DoStuff(m)
```

The above code works, but packages aren't recognized `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`

My question is basically, how do I tell `imp.load_module` that a given module is part of a package?

Comment: What kind of directory structure do you have? Is the `path` you pass to the function the root path of a package?

Comment: Part of the purpose of this question is to understand how to make something a package manually, regardless of it's path. Sure, I could wrench ParsePath around to always try to import directories containing `__init__.py` before any content. I'm guessing that would work, but it is not the right way to solve problems IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly tell Importer Protocol method `load_module` that the module given is part of the package. Taken from [PEP 302 New Import Hooks](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/)

> The built-in `__import__` function
>   (known as PyImport_ImportModuleEx
>       in import.c) will then check to see whether the module doing the
>       import is a package or a submodule of a package.  If it is indeed a
>       (submodule of a) package, it first tries to do the import relative
>       to the package (the parent package for a submodule).  For example if
>       a package named "spam" does "import eggs", it will first look for
>   a
>       module named "spam.eggs".  If that fails, the import continues as an
>       absolute import: it will look for a module named "eggs".  Dotted
>       name imports work pretty much the same: if package "spam" does
>       "import eggs.bacon" (and "spam.eggs" exists and is itself a
>       package), "spam.eggs.bacon" is tried.  If that fails "eggs.bacon" is
>       tried.  (There are more subtleties that are not described here, but
>       these are not relevant for implementers of the Importer
>   Protocol.)
>
> Deeper down in the mechanism, a dotted name import is split up by
>       its components.  For "import spam.ham", first an "import spam" is
>       done, and only when that succeeds is "ham" imported as a submodule
>       of "spam".
>
> The Importer Protocol operates at this level of *individual*
>      imports.  By the time an importer gets a request for
>   "spam.ham",
>       module "spam" has already been imported.

You must then simulate what the built-in import does and load parent packages before loading sub modules.

Comment: I think modules, packages and importing things is the only part of Python that I am straight out unhappy about. I already made a hackish solution a couple of days ago where I did more or less this, but I appreciate that you were able to clear things up. A "you can't do that", if not satisfying, can at least be useful.

Answer (score 2):

The function `imp.find_module` always takes a plain module name without dots, but the documentation of `imp.load_module` says

> The name argument indicates the full module name (including the package name, if this is a submodule of a package).

So you could try this:

```
def ParsePath(path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for source in (s for s in files if s.endswith(".py")):
            name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(source))[0]
            full_name = os.path.splitext(source)[0].replace(os.path.sep, '.')
            m = imp.load_module(full_name, *imp.find_module(name, [root]))
            DoStuff(m)
```

Comment: Well, you have sort of the right idea (apart from some errors in the code you posted, along with the fact that it absolutely doesn't work), but this doesn't actually help. As I explained answering your first comment, I am not looking for a monkey patch. I can make my own monkey patch. I am looking for an **answer**, and this is not it.

Comment: Well, then I'm not understanding your question correctly. You said you are looking for a way to let `imp.load_module` know the module is part of a package, and the way is to give a fully qualified (i.e. dotted) name, which includes the package name.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Good news is that there is a way of doing it, but you have to use a combination of *imp* and *importlib*. Here's an illustrative example:

```
import imp
import importlib
package_path = r"C:\path_to_package"

package_name = "module"
module_absolute_name = "module.sub_module"
module_relative_name = ".sub_module"

# Load the package first
package_info = imp.find_module(package_name, [package_path]) 
package_module = imp.load_module(package_name, *package_info)

# Try an absolute import
importlib.import_module(module_absolute_name, package_name)

# Try a relative import
importlib.import_module(module_relative_name, package_name)
```

This will allow *sub_module* to import using relative module paths because we've already loaded the parent package and the submodule has been loaded correctly by importlib to know what it's being imported relative to.

I believe this solution is only necessary for those of us stuck in Python 2.*, but would need someone to confirm that.